# understanding naming of Junos routing tables

Tags: juniper

Am I correct that `master` RI in Junos can have one and only one `inet.0` table and each user-defined RI can have only one `<RI_name>.inet.0` table? Also, `master` RI can have a single `inet6.0` table and each user-defined RI can have only one `<RI_name>.inet6.0` table? So for example, RI named `foo` can not have a table named `inet.0` or `bar.inet.0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. Here's a list of routing tables on one of our juniper boxes for example, all non-default routing instances are prefixed with `ri-`:

```
teun@juniperbox> show route table ?
Possible completions:
  <table>              Name of routing table
  inet.0
  inet.2
  inet.3
  inet6.0
  inet6.2
  inetflow.0
  iso.0
  ri-cust1.inet.0
  ri-cust1.inet6.0
  ri-cust2.inet.0
  ri-cust2.inet6.0
  ri-dmz.inet.0
  ri-dmz.inet6.0
  (etc)
```